# Size of remaining search space for Vehicle Routing Problem given a partial solution

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science, combinations, machine-learning

The vehicle routing problem is a NP-hard problem that, in its most basic form, involves scheduling routes for *v* vehicles that have to make *n* deliveries in total. So a solution (schedule) has the form of *v* routes, 1 for each vehicle, each route giving the **order** of the deliviers the vehicle has to make. The ultimate goal is to find a schedule that minimizes the total route cost. It can be shown that the total amount of possible schedules is $\frac{(n+v-1)!}{(v-1)!}$ which is quite an enormous search space.

However what I would like to know is, given a partial schedule, how large the remaining search space is, or in other words, how much solutions "follow" from it. Let's say for instance that we have to make 3 deliveries, and have 3 vehicles. A partial solution would be:

```
| Vehicle | Deliveries |
|---------|------------|
| A       | 2, 1       |    
| B       |            |    
| C       |            |
```

We can schedule delivery 3 as the single delivery for B or C, or we can schedule it for A as its first, second, or last delivery. Thus in total there are 5 solutions that "follow" from the partial solution.

Combinatorics has always been my weakness, so I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Hi. As far as i can tell about your statement, if you call $x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_n$ the deliveries that are already done, you have $\sum (x_i+1)$ ways to put the next one. Si if you call $k=\sum x_i$ and you have to do $m$ deliveries, then the total number of ways to do the remaining $(m-k)$ deliveries is $(m-k)*(\sum (x_i+1))+(m-k-1)$ if (m>k)

Comment: @Phicar: $\sum (x_i+1)$ indeed gives 5 when there are 2 deliveries done, which is correct when there are 3 vehicles. However, when only 1 delivery is done, it does not return the correct value of 4, and it does not take the amount of vehicles into account

Comment: Hi i meant $n$ to be the number of vehicles. So if there are 3 vehicles and just 1 delivery hen, without loss of generality, $x_1=1,x_2=0,x_3=0$ so $\sum (x_i+1)=(1+1)+1+1=4$.